# Convert int type to HEX equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, hex, byte

I have crc16 calculation method:

```
private static final int POLYNOMIAL = 0x0589;
private static final int PRESET_VALUE = 0xFFFF;
private static byte[] data = new byte[512];

public static int crc16(byte[] data){
        int current_crc_value = PRESET_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            current_crc_value ^= data[i] & 0xFF;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++ ) {
                if ((current_crc_value & 1) != 0) {
                    current_crc_value = (current_crc_value >>> 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
                }
                else{
                    current_crc_value = current_crc_value >>> 1;
                }
            }
            if ((i+1)%64==0) {
                System.out.println("\nValue: \t"+(~current_crc_value & 0xFFFF));
            }
        }

        current_crc_value = ~current_crc_value;

        return current_crc_value & 0xFFFF;
    }
```

After passing data[] array in the crc16 method, It prints the crc value (calculated) `System.out.println("\nValue: \t"+(~current_crc_value & 0xFFFF));`as:

```
Value:  64301

Value:  63577

Value:  65052

Value:  63906

Value:  65223

Value:  65369

Value:  63801

Value:  64005
```

But actually i want it in HEX format as `0x....` Also i can see that the Value is actually **5 digit** but this need to be 16 bit crc value,  also i can see that all of them has same MSB i.e **6**. Should i omit that value?

I think this is kind of silly question but help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you need to output variables in a specific format, you can use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) for that purpose:

```
System.out.println(String.format("\nValue: \t0x%x", ~current_crc_value & 0xFFFF));
```

- `%x` is the hexadecimal format.
- `0x` is just a plain string here

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try using `Integer.toHexString(int)`

Something like

```
int val = 12345;
String hex = Integer.toHexString(val);
```

and to get them back try this:

```
int i = (int) Long.parseLong(hex, 16);
```